# Imageview not centered in parent - Android

Tags: android, imageview

I'm trying to position the blue icon precisely in the center of the card, but for some reason the icon goes up to the top of the card.
Can someone tell me what's wrong?
Thanks,

Here's a screenshot of my problem:

[image]

```
<GridView
android:id="@+id/documents_grid"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
android:columnWidth="@dimen/document_grid_item_width"
android:gravity="center"
android:horizontalSpacing="0dp"
android:numColumns="auto_fit"
android:stretchMode="spacingWidthUniform"
android:verticalSpacing="48dp" />
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

---

```
<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="0.9"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:foreground="?android:selectableItemBackground"
    android:background="@drawable/document_grid_item_bg">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/draft_more_button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_more" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView5"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/draft_icon" />

    </RelativeLayout>
</FrameLayout>

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_margin="5dp"
    android:layout_weight="0.1">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/draft_date_tv"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:text="Date" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume that in gridview item your parent is LinearLayout which can't be seen from your code snippet. If that's the case, in FrameLayout properties set the height to wrap_content

```
<FrameLayout
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_weight="0.9"
android:focusable="true"
android:foreground="?android:selectableItemBackground"
android:background="@drawable/document_grid_item_bg">
```

Answer (score 0):

Given code snippet is working fine with `LinearLayout` as parent.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.9"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:background="@color/colorGreen"
        android:foreground="?android:selectableItemBackground">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/draft_more_button"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_more" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView5"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/draft_icon"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true" />

        </RelativeLayout>
    </FrameLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.1">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/draft_date_tv"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:text="Date" />
    </RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

**1.** Remove `FrameLayout` and add its `attributes` to child `RelativeLayout`.

**2.** Use `attribute android:src` instead of `app:srcCompat` to set `image` on `ImageView`.

**Try this:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.9"
        android:background="#fff">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/draft_more_button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_more" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView5"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:src="@drawable/draft_icon" />

    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.1">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/draft_date_tv"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:text="16 May 2017" />
    </RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

> **FYI**, If you are using `CardView` as a container, then just put below `LinearLayout` inside your `CardView`.

**OUTPUT:**

[image]